# How do I pass data and push new view controller from collection view embedded in table view embedded in a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've created a view controller that has a table view embedded in it and in each section of the table I have a cell containing a horizontal collection view. [This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjm5B.png) The collection view delegate is hooked up to the table view cell and the table view delegate is hooked up to the main view controller.

I want to segue on a cell tap to a new view controller using the navigation controller's push method and pass data from the collection view cell to the new view controller. However, I can't call that navigation controller's push method from inside my collection view's didSelectItem function as that is nested inside my table view cell and not the actual view controller. Some help would be appreciated, thank you!

This is the main view controller's cellForItem function

```
class SearchController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExploreRow", for: indexPath) as! ExploreRow

    let category = classTypes[indexPath.section]
    cell.configureCell(type: category)

    return cell
}
```

}

and this is the code within the table view cell's didSelectItem for the collection view cell

```
class ExploreRow: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Selected \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

}

The print function works fine but I can't call the navigation controller to push the new view controller from inside that table view.

Comment: You should publish the code in order to facilitate helping you.

Comment: What you describe should work perfectly fine. Is there an error thrown? So long as you are in the ViewController class or extension, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a delegate protocol or call-back closure from your table view cell to the table view controller. Then you have:

- CollectionViewCell tapped
- TableViewCell is CollectionView's delegate - it processes the tap
- In didSelectItem, TableViewCell tells TableViewController which CollectionViewCell was tapped
- TableViewController handles it from there

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thank you so much!